# Use class and methods to get JSON data and echo out content

Tags: php, json, class

I'm trying to use OOP to create an effective class that loops through a JSON file and echo's out certain items. Inside of the class I need to use methods like "getName()" etc. The goal is to use a class as much as possible. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    $file= file_get_contents("swapi.json");
    $data = json_decode($file);
    $content = $data->results; 


    foreach($content as $item){

        $name = $item->name;
        $height = $item->height;
        $person = new Character($name,$height);

        echo $person->getName(),$person->getHeight();                   

    }


    class Character{
        public $name;
        public $height;
        public static $number_of_char = 0;

        function __construct($name,$height){   

            $this->name = $name;
            $this->height = $height;
            Character::$number_of_char++;
        }
        function getName(){

            return "Character number ".Character::$number_of_char.":".'</br>'.
               '<li>'."Namn: ".$this->name.'</li>';
        }
        function getHeight(){

            return '<li>'."height: ".$this->height."cm".'</li>'.'</br>';
        }    
     }
```

JSON

```
{ 

    "count": 87,
    "next": "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "height": "172",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "blond",
```

This is as as compressed as I've managed to get it.

Echos out 10 different objects containing for example:

```
   "Character number 1:"
-  Name: Obi-Wan Kenobi
-  height: 182cm
```

Is this good practice? Iv'e tried using loops inside the class to get the data but haven't been able to make it work. (The 'foreach($content..' is in a separate file)

Comment: The Character object is a subset of the JSON document, so it wont be able to create itself from the document.  I would create a second loader class for the file that loops over the data and outputs an array of Character objects.

Comment: Ok thanks. I suspected that in order to loop through all the data it will have to happen outside the class.
By sending data like this: $person = new Character($name,$height);